# Adding a Filter to Sidbar Login Plugin to Change Login Button Lable

Tags: plugins, filters, login, forms, labels

I'm a newbie and I have not been able to find an answer to my question.
I have installed the Sidebar Login plugin and I'm trying to change the form labels, specifically,the login button label.
 I understand that I need to add a filter to my functions.php file in the child theme in order to modify the following piece of code:

```
$login_form_args = apply_filters( 'sidebar_login_widget_form_args', array(
            'echo'              => true,
            'redirect'          => esc_url( apply_filters( 'sidebar_login_widget_login_redirect', $redirect ) ),
            'label_username'    => __( 'Username', 'sidebar_login' ),
            'label_password'    => __( 'Password', 'sidebar_login' ),
            'label_remember'    => __( 'Remember Me', 'sidebar_login' ),
            'label_log_in'      => __( 'Login &rarr;', 'sidebar_login' ),
            'remember'          => true,
            'value_remember'    => true
        ) );

        wp_login_form( $login_form_args );
```

The filter to change any of the arrays is: sidebar_login_widget_form_args

I have spent an entire day trying to figure out how to properly code the filter without any success. I would greatly appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

In your funtions file, you need to create your function, name it as you like:

```
function my_changein_args ($my_form_args) {
  return array(
    'echo'           => true,
    'redirect'       => esc_url( apply_filters( 'sidebar_login_widget_login_redirect', $redirect ) ),
    'label_username' => __( 'Yourusernamelabel', 'sidebar-login' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Yourpasswordlabel', 'sidebar-login' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Yourrememberlabel', 'sidebar-login' ),
    'label_log_in'   => __( 'Yourloginlabel', 'sidebar-login' ),
    'remember'       => $show_rememberme,
    'value_remember' => true
  );
}
add_filter( 'sidebar_login_widget_form_args', 'my_changein_args' );
```

Don't forget to open and close PHP.